# Error: write EPIPE while connecting to multiple remote databases meteor mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

We are using different databases to store user’s data. For example, user’s general information (login, password, profile info, etc) stored in the main database, but if the user has own contacts, tasks or other information, they will be stored at the separate database.
Connection to the database looks like this:

```
 var userId = this.userId;
   var database = new 
   MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver('mongodb://localhost:27017/' + 
   userId);
   var collection = database.open('tasks');
```

Generally, it works even at the production stage but sometimes Meteor fails to connect to separate databases. I"Error: write EPIPE" & “MongoError: connection to example.com:27017 closed”). So we don’t know why this error occurs.
Here is the screenshot of the logs we’ve got after failing to connect:   https://image.ibb.co/eR74K6/Screen_Shot_2018_01_06_at_11_30_26_AM.png